# Jump to beginning of function in emacs

Tags: emacs

So you're in the middle of a 300 lines function, and want to know where the function declaration is.

How do you do this?

Comment: For java, see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127959/jump-through-java-methods-in-emacs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`M-C-a` jumps to the beginning of the current function.

`M-C-e` jumps to the end of the current function

It works for elisp and c-derived languages (e.g. Java).

Comment: That's Control-Alt-a and Control-Alt-e is it ? doesn't work for me in javascript-mode.

Comment: Try M-x beginning-of-defun. It works for me in javascript-mode

Comment: Aha, indeed ! that key combination was captured by my Desktop Environement. Your solution works perfectly :) ! thanks.

Comment: Works for python function and classes too

Answer (score 10):

typically, i have the `which-function` minor mode enabled which displays the current function on the mode line (using this in my emacs config):

```
(require 'which-func)
(which-function-mode t)
```

Comment: works for elisp files but doesn't work for java. Is it normal?

Comment: probably depends what java mode you are using.  i use JDEE and it works.

Comment: which-function-mode doesn't work well in emacs 23. People on #emacs have reported that it works fine on 24.